# Connecting to Server via Telnet results in 'Could not open connection [...] connection failed'

Tags: port, remote-access, telnet

I'm using this command to connect to my remote server

```
telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 3306
```

but it says

> could not open connection to host on port 3306
>
> Connection failed

Why is this failing and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Update firewall rules to make sure port# 3306 is open on the server that is running the mysql database.